# Overlay Panel with Backbone.js and JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, backbone.js, popup, overlay

I'm trying to create an overlay panel within a project using backbone and JQM. The overlay panel should work like the example described in the JQM documentation:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/popup-panels.html

My project which is based on a first step tutorial for backbone and JQM, uses the backbone routing. Normal routes to changePage() are working well. I just can't get the overlay panel to work.

I created a git repository for my project. If I click the "menu" button in the header, the overlay panel should slide in like in the demo above.

https://github.com/Devthias/BackboneJQM.git

Inside my router I tried to set the data-role attribute to popup bevor calling the changePage function.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes:{
    "":"home",
    "settings":"settings",
    "menuPanel":"menuPanel"
},

initialize:function () {
    // Handle back button throughout the application
    $('.back').live('click', function(event) {
        window.history.back();
        return false;
    });
    this.firstPage = true;
},

....

menuPanel:function(){
    console.log('#menuPanel');
    this.openPopup(new MenuPanelView());
},

changePage:function (page) {
    $(page.el).attr('data-role', 'page');
    page.render();
    $('body').append($(page.el));
    var transition = $.mobile.defaultPageTransition;
    $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {changeHash:false, transition: transition});
},

openPopup:function (page){
    $(page.el).attr('data-role', 'popup');
    page.render();
    $('body').append($(page.el));
    var transition = $.mobile.defaultPageTransition;
    $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {});
}
```

});

Has someone an idea what i'm doing wrong and could help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You may want to try and pass `page` to `openPopup`.

Comment: Yes you're right. I missed the page parameter in the openPopup function.(updated the repository) But the overlay panel is still not shown. Now the site makes a transition to an empty page.

Answer (score 0):

> a **change page** is definitly the wrong move ..

for me it started working as soon as I had a placeholder placed in my template:

```
<div data-role="page">    
  <div data-role="content">

    ...

    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" data-history="false">
      <span>&nbsp;<span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then I the router I did something like:

```
openPopup:function (page){
    $('#myPopup').html($(page.el)).popup('open');
}
```